# Apache prefork.c and other settings

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, httpd.conf, dedicated-server

Intel C2D E7400

2048 MB DDR2 RAM

250 GB 7.200 RPM

Debian 5 - 32bit

This is my dedicated server. I'm using it to host a vBulletin forum. What would be the best **prefork.c, worker.c and mpm_winnt.c** ? I'm having bad laggs with just 100 visitors. This server used to hold at least 1000 without lagging with proper settings.

Anyone could help me with the custom settings? Or give me a link with useful information?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings you're looking to modify (prefork.c/worker.c/mpm_winnt.c) will not help with the problem(s) you're having.  Those settings are used to adjust the spawning and culling of Apache children or threads to serve individual requests.

Your real performance gains are likely to be in the area of your database or your scripting language (PHP in this case).  Your web server is going to give only incremental improvements by comparison.  To test that assertion is easy enough, though: just throw a static file somewhere on your server ("helloworld.txt" or similar) and request it a few thousand times. I all-but-guarantee it loads like a champ. Barring very odd circumstances--like Apache causing swapping--tuning Apache itself is not the answer here.

Comment: I don't think that's the case. It used to run smooth until I reformatted the server without saving my Apache setting. Before reformatting the server I had modified Apache settings, I can't remember what I changed them to.

I'm using vBulletin, no custom php scripts.

Comment: You can modify PHP settings within Apache config files (e.g. with php_flag and php_value).  Perhaps you did this.  However, from a systems point of view, the probability that the bottleneck in your vBulletin application is Apache rather than PHP or MySQL is very nearly zero.  To test is easy enough, though: just throw a static file somewhere on your server ("helloworld.txt" or similar) and request it a few thousand times.  I all-but-guarantee it loads like a champ.  Barring very odd circumstances--like Apache causing swapping--tuning Apache itself is not the answer here.

Comment: +1 for BMDan's test proposed in the comment. Will be good to see it added as part of the answer.

Comment: @Anand Jeyahar: Added to answer, good suggestion.